# How to link multiple tables to a single ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, normalization

I am trying to create a database(using PHP and MYSQL, with XAMPP) which stores information about various fast-food restaurants and their branches,together with the menu offered at their branches.I've created some tables in my database detailing information about the fast-food restaurant,their branches,the category and sub-categories of their menu AND the items they serve in the tables.Extracts/samples of the tables are shown below.

```
Restaurants
+-------------+----------------+
| RestaurantID| RestaurantName | 
+-------------+----------------+
|     1       | PizzaHut       |
|     2       | BurgerKing     |
|     3       | KFC            | 
|     4       | SubWay         |
+-------------+----------------+

Branches
+---------------+----------------+
| RestaurantName| BranchAddress  | 
+---------------+----------------+
|   KFC         | XXX-1234       |
|   KFC         | AAA-1234       |
|   KFC         | YYY-1234       | 
|   BurgerKing  | DDD-1234       |
+---------------+----------------+

Categories
+---------------+----------------+
| BranchAddress | Categories     | 
+---------------+----------------+
|   XXX-1234    | Fries          |
|   AAA-1234    | Burgers        |
|   YYY-1234    | Drinks         | 
|   DDD-1234    | Burgers        |
+---------------+----------------+

SubCategories
+---------------+----------------+
| Categories    | SubCategories  | 
+---------------+----------------+
|   Fries       | Cheese         |
|   Burgers     | Chicken        |
|   Drinks      | Carbonated     | 
|   Burgers     | Beef           |
+---------------+----------------+

Items
+---------------+----------------+
| SubCategories | Items          | 
+---------------+----------------+
|   Cheese      | CheeseFries    |
|   Chicken     | Zinger         |
|   Carbonated  | Pepsi          | 
|   Beef        | Whopper        |
+---------------+----------------+
```

As can be seen above, each restaurant can have several branches, each branches can have several categories, each categories can have several sub-categories, which can then have several items.Branches may have the same categories and/or sub-categories BUT have different items inside of them.

I do not think that a centralised Category,Sub-category and Item table would work in this case as each branch of each restaurant is its own separate individual entity, which would require its own set of categories,sub-categories and item tables.If so, how do i go about creating the tables, as well as setting up the necessary foreign keys?

```
Categories
+----------------+
|  Categories    |
+----------------+
|  Drinks        |
|  Burgers       | 
|  Fries         | 
|  SetMeals      |  
+----------------+

SubCategories
+----------------+----------------+
| Category       |  SubCategories |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Drinks         | Carbonated     |
| Drinks         | Carbonated     |
| Drinks         | Carbonated     |
| Drinks         | Non-Carbonated |
| Burgers        | Beef           |
| Burgers        | Beef           |
| Burgers        | Chicken        |
+----------------+----------------+

SubCategories
+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| Category       |  SubCategories | Items       |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Drinks         | Carbonated     | Pepsi        |
| Drinks         | Carbonated     | Root Beer    |
| Drinks         | Carbonated     | Cola         |
| Drinks         | Non-Carbonated | Orange Juice |
| Burgers        | Beef           | Whopper      |
| Burgers        | Beef           | Cheese Burger|
| Burgers        | Chicken        | McChicken    |
+----------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Of course, i could be wrong, and a centralised tables for may work in this scenario. If so, could i have some examples and/or directions on how to proceed/or go about setting up the tables?

I thought of the following solution:

```
Restaurants
+-------------+----------------+
| RestaurantID| RestaurantName | 
+-------------+----------------+
|     1       | PizzaHut       |
|     2       | BurgerKing     |
|     3       | KFC            | 
|     4       | SubWay         |
+-------------+----------------+

Branches
+---------------+----------------+
| RestaurantName| BranchAddress  | 
+---------------+----------------+
|  KFC          | XXX-1234       |
|  KFC          | AAA-1234       |
|  KFC          | YYY-1234       | 
|  BurgerKing   | DDD-1234       |
+-------------+------------------+

Categories
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| RestaurantName | BranchAddress  | Category       | 
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|  KFC           |     XXX-1234   | Fries          |
|  KFC           |     AAA-1234   | Burgers        |
|  KFC           |     YYY-1234   | Drinks         | 
|  BurgerKing    |     DDD-1234   | Burgers        |
+----------------+----------------------------------+

SubCategories
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| RestaurantName | BranchAddress  | Category       |  SubCategories |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+
|  KFC           |     XXX-1234   | Fries          | Cheese         |
|  KFC           |     AAA-1234   | Burgers        | Chicken        |
|  KFC           |     YYY-1234   | Drinks         | Carbonated     |
|  BurgerKing    |     DDD-1234   | Burgers        | Beef           |
+----------------+---------------------------------+----------------+

Items
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| RestaurantName | BranchAddress  | Category       |  SubCategories | Items       |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+
|  KFC           |     XXX-1234   | Fries          | Cheese         |CheeseFries  |
|  KFC           |     AAA-1234   | Burgers        | Chicken        |Zinger       |
|  KFC           |     YYY-1234   | Drinks         | Carbonated     |Pepsi        |
|  BurgerKing    |     DDD-1234   | Burgers        | Beef           |Whopper      |
+----------------+---------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Although the tables above gives each restaurant and its branches their individual Categories,Subcategories,Items, it defeats the whole purpose of splitting them up in the first place, and is quite silly.

EDIT: I tried to denormalise the above tables so that i could query it using

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Restaurantname='BurgerKing' AND 
BranchAddress='XXX-1234' AND Category='Fries';
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die("Error");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc)
{
extract($row);
echo "$Item";
}
```

***NOTE: I am planning to expand the database to include non fast-food restaurants and even non-F&B related shops in the future, so the various tables (Categories/SubCategories and Items) will have to be able to include categories from non-F&B related shops (E.g Electronics/Books , etc)***

I apologise for extremely long question and would appreciate any advice and help i can get.

Thanks!

Comment: why did you denormalize it as such. why do you have have subcategories by branch address. who knows maybe this is legit. what do you mean it defeats the whole purpose and is silly ?

Comment: @ Drew Pierce I've edited my question to show why i denormalised it as such.I just think it's silly because instead of denormalising it as such, i might as well lump everything into one huge table, then use it like an Excel table, using queries like filters. E.g(SELECT * FROM Item WHERE RestaurantName='KFC';) Without having to use JOINS in my queries, although doing it like this would defeat the whole purpose of a relational database.
@ yvytty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're denormalizing either. You can take the branch-related columns out of categories and subcategories, the category name out of subcategories, etc. By leaving them in you are duplicating a lot of data and this not how you work with relational databases, traditionally! You should also be relating these tables by ID, not by a name, as the comparison when joining is faster.

You can consider linking items to branches with a many-to-many link table. This way, you can fulfill your requirements of being able to relate specific items of a category/subcategory to a branch without relating the entire category/subcategory.

```
CREATE TABLE item_link (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  branch_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  item_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY composite (`branch_id`, `item_id`)
);
```

See this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbfa7/2/0) I made for you that details my proposed changes to your schema and gives an example of how you would use this new table to show the menu / inventory of a branch.

Comment: I denormalised the table so that i would be able to use queries without using any JOINS. What does the keyword KEY do in your fiddle? i tried googling it, but all i got were composite primary keys, which doesn't make sense as you already set a Primary Key prior to using the KEY keyword.(I'm referring to the item_link table as well as the other tables e.g(chains)).

Comment: Denormalization should only be employed in rare occasions, usually when tables are enormous (billions of records) and indexes can't get you by performance-wise. See [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html) by Jeff Atwood for more information. The keyword key adds an index. If you look at the execution plan of the query in the fiddle, you will see that the composite key is used to retrieve records when joining item_link.